# Вытащить числа из массива для splice

Tags: javascript, discord

Хочу вытащить из массива числа, которые получены заранее через цикл, для того чтобы очищать массив от всего не нужного, но не знаю как реализовать это.

```
verque.splice(text)
```

вот так пытаюсь сделать, в итоге очищается весь массив
сам массив:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: verque.splice(text,1)

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему при помощи `var infrc = verque.indexOf()` т.е. `verque.splice(index, [тут id элемента, которое нужно удалить])`

Comment: Может вам глянуть а сторону ```.filter```?